# Spree Products for a particular store in single application integration using spree-multi-domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

I have an existing rails application with Gemfile having gems like below.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'rails_admin'

gem 'spree', '~> 3.7.0'
gem 'spree_multi_domain', github: 'spree-contrib/spree-multi-domain', branch: 'tracker-fix-3-5'
```

But after adding spree gems into my rails application, and running spree installation commands, I have started receiving errors like this:

`Undefined variable: "$navbar-height".`

Below is my css file sample already being used in the application.

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_self
 *= require toastr
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require style
 *= require _all-skins
 *= require slideshow
 *= require custom
 */
```

I even tried to remove bootstrap from my css file and added lines like below:

```
 *= require spree/frontend/all
 *= require spree/backend/all
```

But nothing worked.

Is there any example code where I can get reference of setting up spree in such a way to have multiple stores using their own domains but in a single application to get their data stored?

Comment: Somewhere in your scss you don't have that variable defined.

Comment: @JoshBrody Thanks for the reply, but I am not using scss files or such variables in my application.